# Select previous html tag onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have html scheme like

```
<li>Some text <a href='#' class='click'>Remove</a> <input type='hidden' ></li>
```

And i have OnClick function like

```
$(".click").click(function() {
    // i need to select 'li' and then delete it
    // i have this code, but its not working
    $(this).prev('li').remove();
    return false;
});
```

How do I Select previous html tag onClick ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`li` is not the previous element, but the parent:

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Damn, i spend so many time with this problem since i didnt know that 'li' is parent... :)

Answer (score 3):

`.prev` is for siblings, in your case, `li` is parent, so you could use `.closest`.

```
$(".click").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
        return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 for closest. Saves some headache when you months later innocently modify the html... true story